# How to check if the last 4 characteres are .pdf- VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing a VBA program to download all pdf files from a website.
I need to verify if the link ends in "/.pdf".
Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [help] and take the [tour]. You'll find that this isn't a code writing service, and it's pretty rare for someone to just throw you a bone as FaneDuru did. You'll want to present your best shot at the code, including what's not working and ask for some guidance from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim resultPDF As String
resultPDF = right("your link", 5)
```

If you would put the link in a cell and you will select it:

```
resultPDF = right(ActiveCell.Value, 5)
```

If you have many such links to analize, you must put them in a range. Let us say A:A range. From A2 to A20:

```
  Dim i as long, rng as Range, sh as Worksheet
  Set Sh = ActiveSheet' use here your sheet
  Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A20")
  For i = 2 To 20
      Debug.Print right(rng.Value, 5)
      If right(rng.Value, 5) = "\.pdf" then MsgBox "It is PDF!"
  Next i
```

Comment: After that i have to write de link in a cell

Comment: Whatever... If you write the link in a cell and you will select this cell, then the code will change in this way:  `resultPDF = right(ActiveCell.Value, 5)`. If you have more such links, you can put all of them in a range (Clumn A:A, for instance) and iterate between all cells...